# How to resample a pandas dataframe to hourly mean, taking into account both a time and a column with a string value?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to make an hourly mean of a dataframe in python, by taking into account the date info but also string info in a certain column. Please see the example below.

```
  station                time temperature
0    EHAM 2020-01-01 13:30:00           2
1    EHAM 2020-01-01 13:50:00           5
2    EHAM 2020-01-02 13:30:00           7
3    EHAM 2020-01-02 13:50:00           1
4    EBBR 2020-01-01 13:30:00           6
5    EBBR 2020-01-01 13:55:00           1
6    EBBR 2020-01-02 14:30:00           2
7    EBBR 2020-01-02 14:40:00           3
```

From this example, ideally I would like to get the following new dataframe:

```
  station                time temperature
0    EHAM 2020-01-01 13:00:00         3.5
1    EHAM 2020-01-02 13:00:00           4
2    EBBR 2020-01-01 13:00:00         3.5
3    EBBR 2020-01-02 14:00:00         2.5
```

The code for this dataframe is:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

flights = {'station': ['EHAM','EHAM','EHAM','EHAM','EBBR','EBBR','EBBR','EBBR'],
        'time': [datetime.strptime('1/1/2020 1:30 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),datetime.strptime('1/1/2020 1:50 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),
                 datetime.strptime('2/1/2020 1:30 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),datetime.strptime('2/1/2020 1:50 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),
                 datetime.strptime('1/1/2020 1:30 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),datetime.strptime('1/1/2020 1:55 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),
                 datetime.strptime('2/1/2020 2:30 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'),datetime.strptime('2/1/2020 2:40 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p')],
        'temperature': ['2', '5','7','1','6','1','2','3']}

df = pd.DataFrame(flights, columns = ['station', 'time','temperature'])
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate `mean` with convert `datetimes` to dates by [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
#convert sampel data to numeric
df['temperature'] = df['temperature'].astype(int)

df1 = (df.groupby(['station', df['time'].dt.date], sort=False)['temperature']
         .mean()
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
  station        time  temperature
0    EHAM  2020-01-01          3.5
1    EHAM  2020-01-02          4.0
2    EBBR  2020-01-01          3.5
3    EBBR  2020-01-02          2.5
```

Solution with `Grouper`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['station', pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='D')], sort=False)['temperature']
         .mean()
         .reset_index())

print (df1)
  station       time  temperature
0    EHAM 2020-01-01          3.5
1    EHAM 2020-01-02          4.0
2    EBBR 2020-01-01          3.5
3    EBBR 2020-01-02          2.5
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Follow up - what if I had multiple columns of which I wanted the mean? Say, temperature and windspeed? I like the `Series.dt.date` approach, so maybe you could show me how that is done in that solution?

Comment: @RikHendrickx - only change `['temperature']` to `['temperature', 'col1', 'col2']` - all columns for mean

Comment: Hi! I have another follow-up question, I altered the original question to make it clear. I am looking for the hourly mean this time. I tried changing the `dt.date` in your first solution to `dt.hour`, however this ended up giving me only the hour in the new dataframe, without the date info.

Comment: @RikHendrickx - Then is possible use `['station', df['time'].dt.date, df['time'].dt.hour]` or `['station', df['time'].dt.floor('H')]`